# VirtualBox no arranca ni crea ninguna máquina

Tags: virtualbox

el mensaje de error salta al intentar arrancar cualquiera de mis máquinas de VirtualBox 6.0 sobre Windows 10, tampoco me deja crear ninguna máquina nueva. 
Adjunto captura del error.
[image: imagen del error]

Configuración de la máquina virtual:

[image: configuracion]

Comment: ¿Qué parámetros de configuración le has puesto?

Comment: Acabo de añadir una imagen con la configuración de una de las máquinas

Answer (score 2):

En las opciones de la BIOS

En caso de tener Intel: "Intel Virtualization Technology (VT-x)" Y lo activas.

En caso de tener AMD: "AMD-v" Y lo activas.

Reinicia el ordenador y prueba de nuevo si te lo permite

Answer (score 1):

ya he encontrado la solución. Actualice a la versión 6.0.14 en virtualbox y aparecio el error y lo que hice fue instalar la versión 6.0.12 que era la versión en la que cree las maquinas virtuales que me daban el error y todo funciona correctamente.